# No symbol table loaded. Use the "file" command. [C++, Bazel, windows 10, vscode]

Tags: gdb, bazel

I get

> No symbol table loaded.  Use the "file" command.
>   When I run gdb `main.exe`

I m trying to debug the most simple programme with c++ you can imagine. and I can't debugged, after I **used the Bazel as my build system**.

### src/app.main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    int c = a + b;

    /* code */
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

to build the binary, I run:

> bazel build //src/app:main --run_under=gdb

Then I run:

> gdb main.exe

and I get this output

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\dev\tests\cpp_tests\bazel-tests\bazel-bin\src\app> gdb main.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
"C:\dev\tests\cpp_tests\bazel-tests\bazel-bin\src\app/main.exe": not in executable format: File format not recognized
(gdb) start
No symbol table loaded.  Use the "file" command.
(gdb)
```

If I run:

> `./main.exe`

I get

```
PS C:\dev\tests\cpp_tests\bazel-tests\bazel-bin\src\app> ./main.exe
Hello world
8
PS C:\dev\tests\cpp_tests\bazel-tests\bazel-bin\src\app>
```

What is happening with Bazel?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  `Να σου πο φιλε, a 1ον εισαι legend στο StackOverflow, and thank you for correcting my question.  και 2ον. You have any clue what is happening with the question I made?

Comment: Too much of honor, there are way better _legendary users_ than me. Also I am not very well versed with bazel as a build system. But it looks like you need to set some flags to compile your code in debug mode. I just removed the c++ tag from the question, because that doesn't seem to be the primary culprit at all.